# An algorithm to find highest sum in a set of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, sum, sequence

my question is: I need an algorithm that if I have some lists, in a specific order and I want to find a set of values that gives me the highest sum. The fact is when I take a value, it has to be greater or equal to the last taken. An example:

- List1 `{5, 10, 1}`
- List2 `{9, 8}`
- List3 `{4, 4, 4, 4, 4}`

The right answer is `{1, 5, 8, 9}`

(In fact I take 1 and 5 in the first list, then I discard the 10 because if I'd take it I could not take 9 and 8, which sum is greater than 10. I discard the 4,4,4,4,4 because if I take them, I'd discard all the numbers between 1 and 4 in other arrays).

I hope I'm making myself clear. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the significance of input being a list of lists? Can it be a flat list instead?

Comment: The input can also be a list with an amount of values, given the bounds of the sub lists. example {5, 10, 1, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} first [0, 3] second [3, 5] third [5, 9]

Comment: I don't understand why you need a second dimension, though. To me, the problem sounds like "find an increasing subsequence with the highest sum."

Comment: it seems that the elements in one of the lists can be taken in arbitrary order. What matters is that all elements chosen from the first list come before all elements chosen from the second list, etc. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a variation of the longest increasing subsequence algorithm. The LIS stores the best length found so far, while the algorithm that you need will store the sum of the items taken so far. At the end of the run the highest sum stored in the auxiliary array will provide the answer to your problem.